# Google content experiments on single page apps

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-analytics-api, ab-testing, content-experiments

Has anyone set up successfully the content experiments api on single page apps?

I have a single page app, where I want to run a/b tests. So I decided to try and integrate google experiments.

## How it is set up

For each page I want to test, I have a couple of views.

In the ViewModel for these routes, I have the views in an array:

```
const variations = ['login/original-login.html', 'v1-login.html'];
```

Before my view is rendered, I create a new script tag with the appropriate src and write it to document.

`//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=${experimentId}`

When the script is loaded, I choose the variation by calling
`cxApi.chooseVariation()` and based on the returned value a view is rendered.

```
variations[cxApi.chooseVariation()];
```

At this point, I'm sending an event hit to GA (as per documentation). Because the `pageview` event is sent before cxApi has loaded.

## The problem

As this is a single page app, the window doesn't refresh after I navigate from one route to another. **And this means that the last loaded experiment's data is sent to every GA hit.**

Do you guys have any solution for this problem?
I will be grateful if you can suggest another approach or technology for running experiments in your single page apps.